# How can I prevent someone that didn't login into a page?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I prevent someone that didn't login into a page (control panel) and posting something?

I am using PHP and mysql for the login.

Comment: Isn't that what the login is for? Post the code you're using, otherwise it's impossible to tell you what's wrong

Comment: I didn't make the code yet, I want to know how could I prevent it to then start programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean *from* posting something rather than *and* posting something.  The simple explanation is that on any page that requires authorization, you need to check whether the current user is authorized.   The simplest way to do this with a secure cookie and is built into PHP via the [Session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) module.

On the login page you would have something like:

```
if (log_user_in($username, $password)) {
    $_SESSION['authorized'] = true;
}
```

On pages requiring authorization, you would have a check like:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['authorized']) || !$_SESSION['authorized']) {
    // redirect user away
}
```

Mechanisms for handling the actual logging in and modularizing the session handling/gatekeeping have been done to death and are baked into most CMS or frameworks.  If you are using a CMS or framework, you should look into the specifics of authorization/authentication for it which will probably abstract a lot of what I've told you.